# Android / Java: How to check internet connection in background?

Tags: java, android, internet-connection

I need help regarding monitoring the internet connection in the app.

I would like to monitor the internet connection the whole time, like youtube or whatsapp.

What should I do?

So if the user loses connection show dialog with try again, or start new activity.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please break down your problem in smaller ones, e.g.: "How to execute a code in background" and "How to detect internet connection". Don't forget to show your effort (what you tried so far, where did you get stuck). Please refer to this guide on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Don't forget to research first, here are the official docs on [Determine and monitor the connectivity status](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) and [Guide to background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`BroadcastReceiver`** for checking internet connection in background. BroadCastReceivers allows listen the system  or other applications signals. It's running on the background for listens the specific signals on everytime.

1. Create your special `BroadcastReceiver` class
2. Declare it in your Manifest File

**Note that:** *It will run always in background therefore if you show a toast message when internet connection was lost, even if you terminate your app it will show a toast message again. So you should destroy it when your app destroyed.*

To see how it works: [You can check this basic codes.](https://github.com/burcus/internet-connection)

But if your android version is 7.0 or higher you should use JobSchedular or GcmNetworkManager for this topic.

Comment: Hey welcome, well unfortunately Android removed the internet state change broadcast receiver.

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback. I saw this warning in Android Studio, I will edit my answer :)